# Setting the classpath for a Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, properties, classpath

I've been looking at the questions related to Spring `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` beans and the associated classpaths, but so far have been unable to resolve my issue. I'm doing some changes to an older program called `myApp`, which runs as a Jar and has an external properties file called `myApp.properties' file, which lives in a directory called 'config' within my application directory. In the`applicationContext.xml' file for `myApp' I have a bean defined to read in this external properties file:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
  <list>
    <value>classpath:myApp.properties</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

This application works just fine when built and run within Netbeans, because I include the `config` folder along with all the JAR dependencies for builds and runs. But when I try to run it from the command line using `java -jar myApp.jar`, I get the following error:

```
08/01/2016 15:37:18.562 | ERROR | Unable to start the application. | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [myApp.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I get that I need to specify the classpath correctly so that Spring knows where to find the properties file, but I'm not sure exactly how to do so, so any pointers would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked for me was this:

```
java -cp "myApp.jar;lib/*;config"  com.myCompany.myApp.Main
```

(Yes, the class with the main() method is also called Main. No, I didn't write this program :) )

My classpath specifies the JAR which contains the main class, a directory `lib` containing all the other JARs needed to run this application (using the '*' character to avoid having to write out the name of every JAR in that directory), and the 'config' directory that contains various configuration files. I also figured out that I could specify `myApp.properties` without any qualifiers in the property-configurer definition, allowing me to keep that file in the same directory as 'myApp.jar' without issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try,

java -classpath ".;\config*" -jar myApp.jar

Comment: What does the '*' after "config" specify? I assume it's a wild-card character?

Comment: Actually, using both the -classpath and -jar options doesn't work out, as the classpath specified gets ignored in favour of whatever is in the manifest.mf file contained in the JAR. So what I had to do was just use -classpath and specify the main class explicitly instead of just the JAR

Comment: Also, I've learned in my SO research this afternoon that the '*' is specifically for JAR files (and maybe class files too, IIRC), so using that wouldn't have enabled the program to located my properties file anyway...